# Why isn't JUnit finding my tests?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

To clarify, I'm relatively unfamiliar with Java.

I'm writing a class "GobblerClient" to interact with an API, and to test some of my functions I decided to write a few unit tests using JUnit. I've created a bunch of failing tests, and when I go to run them, it appears that JUnit just fails to find them.

[image: picture of eclipse with failing tests and no tests in the junittest view]

Any ideas why JUnit might not be detecting my tests?

EDIT: The tests in full.

```
package com.gobbler;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class GobblerClientTest {

    @Test
    public void testDisplay_name() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testUser_id() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuthenticity_token() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testClient_key() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGobblerClient() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuthenticate() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet_data() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSha1hmac() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Comment: A screenshot is no use.  Paste the code into the question properly.

Comment: Could you expand the import list ?

Comment: Sorry- just wanted to show the tests weren't appear in the left panel. I added the actual code above.

Comment: All tests fail for me. Just open the class and use "CTRL+SHIFT+d" t or right click on class -> run with junit

Comment: right click on the source folder and select "run as junit test" and tell us what happens. btw, i usually put the test case code in another source folder like Gobbler/tst/

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project is an Android project, if that's significant. However, not of the code relies on Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JUnit dialog is empty until you run some tests, it shows the results of the last run.

An easy way to do this is right-click on your class (either in the Package Explorer or the class name in your source code) and select `Run As` -> `JUnit Test`

If no tests appear at this point, try again with `Run As` -> `Run Configurations...` and in the Run dialog that appears ensure that the "Test runner" drop-down is set to "JUnit 4". If it is set to an earlier version it will not detect your @Test annotations.

Edit: Since you are using Android rather than the standard JVM, you need to perform some additional setup, see my comments.

Comment: I tried that (the screenshot is mid-Run) but it's always just blank.

Comment: Debug and see where it gets stuck. The simple fact that you were able to take a screenshot mid-run is weird considering your empty tests.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I've just realised you added that you are using Android - there is more setup to do for that. You need to include the InstumentationTestRunner and use `Run As` -> `Android Junit Test`. This is regardless of whether you are using any of the Android platform code (your classes are not Java bytecode they are Dalvik). See the developer docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_eclipse.html

Comment: To be honest unit testing in Android is a pain in the ass at the best of times. There are some good tutorials on the Web though - just remember you are no longer running under the standard JVM and everything has to execute within the emulator, including simple tests. Unless you use a third-party library like Roboelectric.

Answer (score 0):

A few guesses: perhaps your Eclipse is already running a previous junit session which got stuck for some reason; pressing "Terminate" and trying again might help.

Another thing you might want to check is your Eclipse version; if it's too old its embedded junit runner might not recognize Junit's annotations, which were included in junit 4.x if I'm not mistaken.

One final guess would be trying to check if the actual junit test is included in your project's build path (although this is very unlikely since you were able to make Eclipse start running your test).

Comment: So it's certainly not the first case. I've tried restarting Eclipse and rerunning with no success.

I'm running Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 1 on a relatively new machine (and created the tests with the specification that be junit4) so that isn't quite it either.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me, in IBM Rational Application Developer 8.5.
In my case, it seems the problem was due to my having configured the project with the default JDK (which is IBM's JDK used for WebSphere).  Switching to vanilla JDK 1.6 fixed it for me.  I suspect the real reason is not the actual version of the JDK - but the switch was good enough to allow me to move on ... :-)